# In cocoa, NSTextField does not respond

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have written NSTextField with source code only. But NSTextField is not clickable and keyboard events do not work either.

```
open class SearchBarView: ViewWrapper, NSTextFieldDelegate {
var textField: NSTextField!

---- TextField init
textField = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 60))
textField.isEditable = true
textField.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(28.0))
textField.textColor = NSColor.gray
textField.isSelectable = true
textField.delegate = self

self.addSubview(self.textField)

---- func
open override func controlTextDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
{
    Swift.print("asdasd")
    let object = notification.object as! NSTextField
    self.textField.stringValue = object.stringValue
}
```

[image]

How can I get the keyboard to fix it?

Comment: What does `ViewWrapper` do? Which control is focused? Is `isEnabled` true?

Comment: are you using custom window wherever you are placing your textfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make NSTextfield to work and if you are using custom window please check if your window is keyWindow() and mainWindow() YES.

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow {
    return YES;
}
```

Try your swift code for if you have custom window.